# Adding image and changing text font size in PopupPanel not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have code in Google Apps Script for popupPanel, all other properties are working except for adding image and changing the text font size. I have to add small image just below the label text and I have created the perma link for the image with sharing option "Anyone with the link can view". I have used `img src` property for image and `fontSize` property for text size. Here is my code:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();

    // Create a popup panel and set it to be modal.
    var popupPanel = app.createPopupPanel();

    popupPanel.add(app.createHTML("Your application has been successfully submitted!<br/><br/>Thank You!<br/><br/><img src='https://docs.google.com/uc?id=..........'/>")).setSize(900, 610).setPopupPosition(370,1208).setStyleAttribute('color','#336600').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','60px').setStyleAttribute('fontWeight','bold').setStyleAttribute('backgroundColor','#FFFFE0');

    popupPanel.show();
```

I have used dots in above code in place of fileid of image for privacy.

Any idea on this one please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a fan of popup panels because I don't like them so much but I think they have the same restrictions as HTML widgets in UiApp and Google published a list of authorized html tags that one can use in this context.

The list is as follows :  **B, BLOCKQUOTE, BODY, BR, CENTER, CAPTION, CITE, CODE, DIV, EM, H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, HR, I, LABEL, LEGEND, LI, OL, P, SPAN, STRONG, SUB, SUP, TABLE, TBODY, TD, THEAD, TITLE, TR, TT, UL.**

and the [release note](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2012) where I found this was published in march 2012 (search the page on "march")

As you can see, the `img` tag is not in the list so it won't work.

As a workaround, use the [image class widget](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/image) to show the image by adding it to the panel.

Comment: Thanks Serge insas for your answer. As only one child widget can be used inside popupPanel, I have to make another popupPanel without border for image and put that inside main popupPanel to make this work. This is the code I added:

 var popupPanelnew = app.createPopupPanel();
    popupPanelnew.add(app.createImage("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=........").setStyleAttribute('width', '100px').setStyleAttribute('height', '100px')).setSize(60, 60).setPopupPosition(780,1700).setStyleAttribute('backgroundColor','#FFFFE0').setStyleAttribute('border', 'none');

Thanks

Comment: You can also use any other panel inside the popup panel (horizontalPanel, VerticalPanel...)- Thanks for accepting ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Serge insas.